# How do you deep copy a vector of derived class pointers via the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
//#include "V2d.h"
using namespace std;

class item {
public:
    int value;
    string description;
    item() {}
    virtual ~item() {}
    virtual void display() {
        cout << "Value: " << value << endl;
    }
};

class Cat : public item {
public:
    string name = "Cat";
    Cat() {
        value = 20;
        description = "a cat";
    }
    void display() {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Value: " << value << endl;
        cout << "Description: " << description << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

class Dog : public item {
public:
    string name = "Dog";
    Dog() {
        value = 10;
        description = "a dog";
    }
    void display() {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Value: " << value << endl;
        cout << "Description: " << description << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

class v2d {
public:
    int hitPoints;

    enum ItemName {
        APPLE, ORANGE
    };
    vector<item*> inventory;
    v2d() {
    }
    ~v2d() {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
            delete inventory[i];
        }

        inventory.clear();

    }
    v2d(const v2d& orig) : inventory(orig.inventory.size()) {

        hitPoints = orig.hitPoints;
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); ++i) {
            inventory[i] = new item(*orig.inventory[i]);
        }
        cout << "Copied!" << endl;
    }
    void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
            inventory[i]->display();
        }
    }

};
int main() {
    v2d vect1;
    vect1.inventory.push_back(new Cat());
    vect1.inventory.push_back(new Dog());
    vect1.inventory.push_back(new Dog());
    vect1.inventory.push_back(new Cat());
    vect1.inventory.push_back(new Dog());
    vect1.display();

    cout << "**************************\n" << endl;

    v2d vect2(vect1);
    vect2.display();
}
```

**And where would I start with trying to overload the += and -= operators in v2d to subtract and add to the inventory vector?**
I have gotten to the part of having the base class and the derived classes; I seem to be having trouble *not* using dynamic casting. Is there a simple way to deep copy a vector of derived class pointers via the copy constructor without using a clone() function?

Comment: You can use a virtual `clone` method that each derived class can override. Also, consider using smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: `delete inventory[i];` -- Your `item` class does not have a virtual destructor.  Thus this line of code will invoke undefined behavior if the pointer being deleted is derived from `item`.  Also, consider this: `v2d vect1; Dog d; vect1.inventory.push_back(&d);` -- That will also invoke undefined behavior, since `d` was not allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this correctly two more things need to be added to the base class:

```
class item {
public:

    virtual ~item() {}
```

The base class must have a virtual destructor.

```
    virtual item *clone() const=0;
```

And an abstract method that's traditionally called `clone()`. Every one of your subclasses must implement `clone()`, typically by using a copy constructor:

```
class Cat : public item {
public:

    item *clone() const override { return new Cat{*this}; };
```

The same thing is done for all other subclasses of `item`. Then, with this in place you can clone a vector of these objects, correctly:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); ++i) {
        inventory[i] = orig.inventory[i]->clone();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I seem to be having trouble not using dynamic casting. Is there a simple way to deep copy a vector of derived class pointers via the copy constructor without using a clone() function?

`clone` is the traditional solution, but I will propose an alternative.

Consider using type erasure and value types. It will give the simplest use, *by far*, with more complexity to set it up. Value types generally interoperate more cleanly with a lot of the language and library. They are less intrusive. Standard types can satisfy your interfaces. There is no inheritance required. Value types do not require pointers and indirection everywhere. Those are but a few of the advantages.

With C++20, we can define a concept for `item`, which is an interface by another name:

```
template <typename Item>
concept item = std::copyable<Item> && requires(const Item& const_item, Item& item) {
    { item.value() } -> std::same_as<int&>;
    { const_item.value() } -> std::same_as<const int&>;
    { item.description() } -> std::same_as<std::string&>;
    { const_item.description() } -> std::same_as<const std::string&>;
    { item.display() };
    { const_item.display() };
};
```

Prior to C++20, concepts were generally implicit or documented, but not entities in code. But in C++20, we can define them. Note that this formulation requires `std::copyable` so any `item` satisfying this will be copyable, using the standard copy constructor. Also, note that raw data members in an interface complicate things slightly, so I replaced them with accessors while still allowing the public read and write access the code in the question allows.

With the interface defined, one can then define a type-erased version: define a type `any_item` satisfying `item` which can itself hold a value of any type satisfying `item`. You will likely find many online sources about type erasure, and the choices involved. The key is to have storage for the object, and a table of function pointers for the interface (a vtable). One can store the object on the heap or have a small internal buffer for small objects. One can store the vtable inline or store a pointer to the vtable. One can write the vtable explicitly, or rely on a hidden class hierarchy to coerce the compiler into writing one. One can even rely on a library (e.g. dyno) to do this for you.

Note that all this complexity is handled by the interface or library author. The user does not have to inherit anything. The user does not have to define boilerplate `clone` functions. The user only has to define the functions the concept requires. Then the user can use the type-erased type, and use it like any other value type. The user can put them in a `std::vector` and watch the copy constructor just work.

Code that looked like:

```
std::vector<item*> inventory;

~v2d()
{
    for (auto* item: inventory) {
        delete item;
    }
}

v2d(const v2d& orig) :
    inventory(orig.inventory.size())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
        inventory[i] = new item(*orig.inventory[i]);
    }
    cout << "Copied!" << endl;
}

vect1.inventory.push_back(new Cat());
```

Becomes:

```
// just use values
std::vector<any_item> inventory;

// destruction just works
~v2d() = default;

// copy just works
v2d(const v2d& other) :
    inventory(other.inventory)
{
    std::cout << "Copied!\n";
}

// just use values, again
vect1.inventory.push_back(cat());
```

[See an example](https://godbolt.org/z/b8ETa8os6)